# Google Sheets: How can I return an array of all values from a column that have a certain corresponding value in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, pivot, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I need (and have had difficulty arriving at) a formulaic way to produce the values shown in columns D, E, and F.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:B; "select max(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A")
```

### update 1:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(IF(A2:B="",,A2:B&"​"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "​"))))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
={"School Supplies"; FILTER(B2:B, A2:A="School Supplies")}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the values grouped together as in the example. I tried your solution in the linked worksheet titled "player0" so you can see what I mean. Also, I will need it to be 3 formulas because in the real example, I am using multiple sheets. Each value in column A has a corresponding sheet that is meant to list all the corresponding values in B.

Comment: Man, you are fast. Is there any chance to break this into 3 formulas? With logic like: "Here’s a list of all values in B whose counterpart in A is 'Clothing'", and so on

Comment: @MichaelSwarts sure, see update 2

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. The final formula is very easy to use too!